# Why is there weird shading on on of the edges?

Tags: rendering, mesh, vertices, shaders, edges

so i have been working on a blender and it was going fine until I found something weird on my mesh. There was strange shading on one of my edges. here is a picture. The edge that is highlighted is the one with the weird shading.

[image]

Here is an even closer close up.

[image]

I don't know if this is a big deal or not, but it is really bothering me and i don't want it to mess the mesh up further down in the future. If anyone has a fix for this, please tell me because this is really bothering me. I made sure to check to see if there was any double vertices of edges but there was none. As i said earlier, I don't know if this is a big or not, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: Probably you have doubles. In Edit Mode, hit "W" and select "Remove Doubles"

Comment: @metaphor_set, yes doubles or overlapping surfaces

Comment: 95% these are overlapping faces, they cant always get removed by the remove doubles

Comment: I would suggest to knife (cut) just a small portion (in case not to publish your .blend file) then delete everything else  and save it with deferent name and upload it so we can see what is happening ;)

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys :) It was an overlapping face. I've fixed it know so thanks for the help.